# Почему выводит неполную информацию о файле изображения?

Tags: c, массивы

Тут странная ситуация с программой выходит:
Если вводить текст вручную или подавать его из файла, то информация выводится как надо.
Если же попытаться загрузить информацию из файла изображения xxx.jpg, то почему-то печатает только первые четыре байта, хотя информацию передаёт и записывает как следует. То есть на выходе получается тоже изображение.

Я думал, что он грешит на 00 в HEX данных изображения, но информацию передаёт нормально, только не выводит её почему-то...

Извиняюсь за польский, но думаю, что не критично.

Вот код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <string.h>

#define READ        0
#define WRITE       1
#define N 10000000

char string[N];
char hex[2*N];

void clear(char *tab, int par)
{
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < par; i++)
    {
        tab[i] = 0;
    }
}

void clear_stdin()
{
    int c;
    while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF){
        continue;
    }
}

char plik_read(char* string, int par)
{
    FILE *file;
    char ADRES[256];
    printf("Wpisz adres pliku razem z formatem! \n");
    fflush(stdout);
    
    if (strchr(ADRES, '\n') == NULL) {
        clear_stdin();
    }
    
    if (fgets(ADRES, 256, stdin) == NULL) {
        /* Ma miejsce błąd lub został przeczytany EOF */
    }
    else {
        /* Usuwamy symbol końca wierza */
        size_t last = strlen(ADRES) - 1;

        if (ADRES[last] == '\n')
            ADRES[last] = '\0';

        /* Tutaj można przeanalizować wiersz */
    }
    printf("\n\n");
    if ((file = fopen(ADRES, "r+")) == NULL)
    {
        printf("Nie udalo sie otworzyc pliku, uruchom ponownie! \n");
        _exit(0);
    }
    else
    {
        int i = 0;
        while(!feof (file) && i<par) {
            if (fread(string , sizeof(char), par, file))
            {
                printf("%s", string);
                i += par;
            }
        }
        fclose(file);
    }
    return *string;
}

char plik_write(char* string, int par)
{
    int fp;
    fp = creat("file.dat", S_IREAD|S_IWRITE);
    if (fp == -1)
    {
        printf ("Nie moge utworzyc file.dat \n");
        _exit(0);
    }
    write (fp, string, par);
    close (fp);
    
    return *string;
}

int main()
{       
        if(fork() == 0)
        {
            char c='N';
            printf("Dane znajduja sie w pliku? Y/N? --> ");
            fflush(stdout);
            scanf ("%c", &c);
            printf("\n");

            if(c=='Y')
            {
                c='N';
                printf("To jest /dev/urandom ? Y/N? --> ");
                
                clear_stdin();
                    
                scanf ("%c", &c);
                if (c == 'Y')
                {                   
                    int U;
                    printf("Podaj liczbe odczytanych bajtow: ");
                    scanf ("%d", &U);
                    
                    plik_read(string, U);
                    printf("\n\n");
                    plik_write(string, U);
                    clear(string, U);
                }
                else
                {
                    plik_read(string, N);
                    printf("\n\n");
                    plik_write(string, N);
                    clear(string, N);
                }           
            }
            else
            {
                printf("Wpisz tekst: \n\n");
                fflush(stdout);
                
                if (strchr(string, '\n') == NULL) {
                clear_stdin();
                }
                
                fgets(string, N, stdin);
                printf("\n");
                plik_write(string, N);  
                clear(string, N);
                //~ for(int i=0; i<strlen(string); i++)
                //~ printf("%c", string[i]);    
            }
            
            /* tablica przechowujaca uchwyty na pliki odczytu i zapisu */
            int pdes[2];
            /* tworzymy pipe skladajaca sie z uchwytu do plikow do odczytu
            * i do zapisu (R i W); deskryptory zostana umieszczone w tablicy */
            pipe(pdes);
            
            if(fork() == 0)
                {
                    
                    FILE *fp;
                    
                    /* zamykamy niepotrzebny deskryptor */
                    close(pdes[READ]);

                        sleep(1);
                        fp = fopen("file.dat", "r+");           
                    
                            while(!feof (fp)) {
                                if (fread(string , sizeof(char), N, fp))
                                printf("%s \n", string);
                            }
                            fclose(fp);
                            
                            int len = strlen(string);

                              // Konwertowanie string to hex
                              
                              for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < len; ++i, j += 2)                            
                                sprintf(hex + j, "%02x", string[i] & 0xff);

                            printf("%s \nin hex is \n%s\n\n", string, hex);
                            
                            clear(string, N);

                        /* wysylamy podany ciag znakow przez pipe */
                        write(pdes[WRITE], hex, strlen(hex));

                }
                else
                {
                    if(fork()==0)
                    {
                        /* zamykamy niepotrzebny deskryptor */
                        close(pdes[WRITE]);

                            /* odbieramy cag znakow z pipe */
                            read(pdes[READ], hex, sizeof(hex));
                            
                            int len = strlen(hex);
                            
                            for (int i=0, j=1; i<len; j++)
                            {                               
                                fprintf(stderr, "%c%c ", hex[i], hex[i+1]);
                                    if(j==15)
                                    {
                                        fprintf(stderr, "\n");
                                        j = 0;
                                    }
                                i+=2;
                            }
                            clear(hex, 2*N);
                    }
                }
        }
        
    for(;;)
    pause();
        
    return 0;
}
```

Вот HEX данные изображения:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот результат работы программы (изображение на выходе нормальное):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: критично то, что не приведён [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посмотрим на эти строки

```
int len = strlen(string);
// Konwertowanie string to hex
                          
for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < len; ++i, j += 2)                            
  sprintf(hex + j, "%02x", string[i] & 0xff);

printf("%s \nin hex is \n%s\n\n", string, hex);
```

В string хранится собственно массив с данными. strlen считает размер до первого нулевого символа (а он в этом массиве 5, если смотреть на картинку дампа). Поэтому, цикл и работает до 4. И выводит только 4 байта.

Давайте пофиксим минимальными жертвами. fread возвращает кол-во прочитанных "объектов", что в нашем случае равно количеству байт. sizeof(char) обычно равен 1 (в с++ с этим строго-строго, а вот о си я не знаю точных гарантий).

```
int len = fread(string , sizeof(char), N, fp)
fclose(fp);
// теперь len хранит реальный размер в байтах                        

// Konwertowanie string to hex
                          
for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < len; ++i, j += 2)                            
  sprintf(hex + j, "%02x", string[i] & 0xff);

printf("%s \nin hex is \n%s\n\n", string, hex);
                        
clear(string, N);
```

также там дальше используется strlen, где можно было бы размер и так посчитать

--- upd ---

как вывести весь файл в консоль в хекс виде

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    FILE* f= fopen("/etc/hosts", "r");
    if (!f) {
        perror("no file");
        return -1;
    }
    char b[1];
    while(fread(b, sizeof(b), 1, f)) {
        printf("%02X ", b[0]);
    }
    fclose(f);
}
```

да, способ не очень эффективный, но для понимания подойдет. Лучше читать кусками по 4-8 килобайт.

Comment: Тут я понял, буду исправлять. А почему здесь: ```  while(!feof (file) && i<par) {
            if (fread(string , sizeof(char), par, file))
            {
                printf("%s", string);
                i += par;
            }
        } ``` printf не выводит целый файл?

Comment: а что Вы ожидаете увидеть в качестве "целого файла"? просто набор непонятных символов? если да, то тут та же ситуация - оно упрется в нулевой символ и остановится. в си указатели не хранят размер "привязанных данных". Кстати, использование `while(!feof(file)) {...}` - плохой паттерн - будете читать лишнее.

Comment: Тогда как вывести всё, включая нулевой символ, до конца файла? Что предлагаете использовать вместо `while(!feof(file)) {...}`? И вот вопрос насчёт предложенного вами решения: если передавать в длину len возвращённое значение fread выходит N элементов, потому что массив string определён статично. Так вот эти N элементов оно будет выводить час, если выведет. N меньше сделать не могу. Что предложите?

Comment: ох, если в файле нет данных достаточно, то зачем все выводить? fread возвращает реально прочитанное кол-во байт, вот его и нужно выводить.

Comment: в бинарном файле нет признака конца файла. Нет никакого "особого байта". В текстовом режиме такое есть. Поэтому, если Вы записали 10миллионов байт, то размер будет 10миллионов. Без знания структуры бинарных данных никак не получить размер. Скорее всего Вам нужно хранить Ваш размер отдельно и записывать только нужное количество байт.

Comment: Тогда я не понимаю, почему у меня не работает ваше решение. Если вписать N вместо len, то всё работает. Ежели использовать len, определённый таким образом: `while(!feof (fp)) {
                                if (len = fread(string , sizeof(char), N, fp))
                                printf("%s \n", string);
                            }`  , - то ничего не выходит.

Comment: а распечатайте значение len. Оно скорее всего у Вас будет равно нулю.

Comment: Ещё лучше, оно его просто не выводит.

Comment: тут есть вопрос. либо Вы его в условие завернули, тогда да, оно нулевое (и поэтому не выводит). либо там проблема глубже

Comment: Глубже. Я пробовал его доставать из условия, всё равно значение не выводит. Ладно, я использую параметр N. Думаю, это будет правильно. Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Хотя, конечно, хотелось бы понять в чём причина...

Comment: Интересно так же поведение strlen в конце. Дело в том, что я возвращаю длину через len =strlen(hex) в конце и вроде бы всё нормально, но оно перестаёт выписывать на 8000 строчке дампа.